# .net core ef saving related data results in error SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, ef-core-2.0

Following [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/related-data), I have tried to do the same in my web app:

```
                    var content = new Content()
                    {
                        IsActive = true,
                        Link = new Link()
                        {
                            DateCreated = DateTime.UtcNow,
                            LinkName = model.Name,
                            LinkDesc = model.Description,
                            LinkPath = model.LinkPath,
                            IsActive = true
                        }
                    };
                    _context.Contents.Add(content);
                    _context.SaveChanges();
```

This throws an error:

> SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in
>   table 'Links' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

But it works if I do this:

```
 var content = new Content() {
   IsActive = true
 }
 _context.Contents.Add(content);
 _context.SaveChanges();

  var link = new Link()
  {
      DateCreated = DateTime.UtcNow,
      LinkName = model.Name,
      LinkDesc = model.Description,
      LinkPath = model.LinkPath,
      IsActive = true,
      ContentId = content.ContentId
  };

  _context.Links.Add(link);
  _context.SaveChanges();

  content.LinkId = link.LinkId;
  _context.SaveChanges();
```

These are the models:

```
public class Content
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int ContentId { get; set; }

        public int? LinkId { get; set; } = null;
        [ForeignKey("LinkId")]
        public virtual Link Link { get; set; }

        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;

        public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    }

public class Link
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int LinkId { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(300)]
        public string LinkDesc { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(50)]
        [Required]
        public string LinkName { get; set; }

        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(500)]
        public string LinkPath { get; set; }

        public int ContentId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ContentId")]
        public virtual Content Content { get; set; }
    }
```

Am I missing anything? Why would the first code try to insert a value to `LinkId`?

Comment: Why do you have foreign keys in both directions? Can you only have one link per content and one content per link?

Comment: Yes, I added the second trying to figure out why it doesn't work properly

Comment: Assuming you can have multiple links per content, I would remove the LinkId and Link fields from the Content class and add an IEnumerable<Link> to the content class so that your relationships are represented correctly.  Once your model is correct see if you still have the same problem.

Comment: Its 1 to 1 or 0, some contents have one Link some don't.

Comment: In which case Content should have a nullable LinkId like you have with a Link navigation property and Link should not have a ContentId but could have an IEnumerable<Content> navigation property

Comment: But why `IEnumerable`? There is a maximum of one `Link` per `Content`

Comment: Right so the way you would do that would be to have a table of contents with a foreign key that points to the Link table.  So each content can have a maximum of one link, but a link can belong to 0 to many Contents,so the IEnumerable would be an IEnumerable<Content> inside the Link class.  You don't have to create the property since you probably wouldn't be accessing it that way, but that's how the relationship works